# How to preview the swiper slides in Full screen when user clicks on the Image or [] icon in react js?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm new to swiper features, I've used swipper component to my project https://swiperjs.com/demos

How to apply full screen mode when user clicks(include thumbnail) on the image slide or **[]** icon?

I have installed  `"swiper": "^6.5.1"` package `npm i swiper@6.5.1` to my project and everything working good,
but 'm unable apply full screen preview mode when user clicks on image or  **[]** icon in the slide. the main idea is, show the image in full screen (include thumbnail in the bottom of the slide) when user want's to see the slide's image only in full screen.

Or, is there any other related packages are  available in npm to achieve the below results in reactJS ? could you please help me on this?.

[slider design example](http://bikewale.com/royalenfield-bikes/himalayan/images/)

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Controller, Thumbs } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
import './styles.css';

SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Controller, Thumbs]);
   
function App() {
  const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState(null);
  const [controlledSwiper, setControlledSwiper] = useState(null);

  const slides = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    slides.push(
      <SwiperSlide key={`slide-${i}`} tag="li">
        <img
          src={`http://localhost:3000/logo512.png`}
          style={{ listStyle: 'none' }}
          alt={`Slide ${i}`}
        />
      </SwiperSlide>
    );
  }

  const thumbs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    thumbs.push(
      <SwiperSlide key={`thumb-${i}`} tag="li" style={{ listStyle: 'none' }}>
        <img
          src={`http://localhost:3000/logo192.png`}
          alt={`Thumbnail ${i}`}
        ></img>
      </SwiperSlide>
    );
  }

 
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Swiper
        id="main"
        thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper }}
        controller={{ control: controlledSwiper }}
        tag="section"
        wrapperTag="ul"
        navigation
        pagination
        spaceBetween={0}
        slidesPerView={1}
        onInit={(swiper) => console.log('Swiper initialized!', swiper)}
        onSlideChange={(swiper) => {
          console.log('Slide index changed to: ', swiper.activeIndex);
        }}
        onReachEnd={() => console.log('Swiper end reached')}
      >
        {slides}
      </Swiper>

      <Swiper
        id="thumbs"
        spaceBetween={5}
        slidesPerView={3}
        onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
      >
        {thumbs}
      </Swiper>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

styles.css

```css
.swiper-container {
      width: 500px;
    }

    .swiper-pagination {
      bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .swiper-wrapper {
      padding-inline-start: 0;
    }
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "swiper": "^6.5.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, I have the same question. have you found any solution for it by now?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same thing a week ago, and as far as am concerned, swiper has no such thing(yikes). but there is another package called fancy-box https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/react/.
first of all, you need to create a Fancybox component:
Fancybox.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

import { Fancybox as NativeFancybox } from "@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox.esm.js";
import "@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox.css";

function Fancybox(props) {
  const delegate = props.delegate || "[data-fancybox]";

  useEffect(() => {
    const opts = props.options || {};

    NativeFancybox.bind(delegate, opts);

    return () => {
      NativeFancybox.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  return <>{props.children}</>;
}

export default Fancybox;
```

after that, you just need to import Fancybox component(which you just created) in the component you want to use this package in and just place it inside of jsx(anywhere really)

```
<Fancybox options={{ infinite: false }}></Fancybox>
```

and most important thing: you need to write this attribute on images of your choice:

```
data-fancybox="gallery"
```

Comment: `fancyapps/fancybox` is NOT free

Comment: it is free.....

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I was searching for the same issue and hope my comment help someone else.
Seems that Swiper 10.3.1 still doesn't have such feature.

So my workaround this is the following:

- Assuming that you already have Swiper on a page.
- You already have the images for the Swiper.
- Assuming that your Swiper is on some nested page (like mysite.com/posts/post-123)
- You can create a modal in higher component (maybe look into React Portals)
- Define a global state for opening and closing the modal.
- Define a global state for the swiper images; the images which should be displayed in the swiper in this current page
- Implement a Swiper in the modal (maybe re-used the one you already have in the page) and grab the images from the global state.

On the Swiper component you have "onClick" prop which can trigger the displaying of the modal (using the global state responsible for displaying the modal).

If you want to dig deeper, the event on the onClick={(e) => ....} has an activeIndex value.

So if the clicked image is on activeIndex 2 for example, the modal will load from this index if you decide to pass it.

Also if you are re-using the same Swiper component for the modal and for the page, consider preventing the onClick on the modal image. Maybe something like
if (isModalOpen) return;
So you don't trigger the function responsible for showing the modal.

Best of luck!

Answer (score -2):

You Can use PhotoSwipe when you click on image in your swiper https://photoswipe.com/, i have implemented similar in my application.